# How to import csv in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I want to import my csv file into postgresql and I make query for importing like below:

```
COPY my_tablename(id, prov, "name", pop1996)
FROM '/Home/users_data.csv'
WITH DELIMITER ','
CSV;
```

But I am getting below error:

```
ERROR: could not open file "Home/users_data.csv" for reading: No such file or directory
SQL state: 58P01
```

How do I resolve it, kindly suggest me.

Hope for reply

Thanks

Comment: Filenames for the `copy` command need to be specified as seen **on the server** where Postgres is running. Does the file `/Home/users_data.csv` exist **on the server**? If you are trying to import a file from your local computer using `psql` you need to use `\copy` which is a `psql` command: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/COPY

Comment: yes, `users_data.csv` file exist in the home folder.

Comment: On the **server**? And it is readable for the `postgres` user? (under which the database database service is running?)

Comment: How to check the file is readable or not for postgres user.

Comment: Log in as the `postgres` (Linux!) user, e.g. using `sudo` then use `cat` or `tail` or something.

Comment: That has nothing to do with Postgres. It's about using your operating system.

Comment: I have these permissions `drwxr-xr-x` for accessing the `Home ` folder means I have permission for access the `users_data.csv file`

Comment: Again: it's not *you* that needs the permissions. It's the user under which the Postgres database is running (typically `postgres`)

Comment: so, what can i do, did you have any solution to resolve this issue

Comment: The error message mentions `Home/users_data.csv` without a leading slash while the query has `/Home/users_data.csv` with a leading slash. One of them is wrong and if it's the one in the query, then the error is expected. Absolute paths must be used.

Comment: I remove the leading slash from the path but the error still come.